# Sending an extra percentage of a token someone is trading to a cold wallet storage address

Tags: fees

I have an erc20 token I want to start trading.  In the smart contract, can you make it send 1% of the transaction amount in the token being sent to a "company wallet" storage along with the wallet it is going to?  Not in gas, but 1% of the amount of the token being traded, or should that be handled in the custom wallet?  Yes or no, will be fine, I'm gonna have to have somebody write it!

Comment: I guess the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: Show your code please.